# Having trouble passing in --node-args with pm2

Tags: javascript, ubuntu-server

I make my scripts on windows then put them on my ubuntu server. This is my first time trying to pass args into the script on start up.
It works on windows I run

`node file.js --variable=value`

Then in my code I grab it with

`const passedIn = require(argv.variable);`

I cant figure out how to make this work with pm2.

I have been trying

`pm2 start file.js --name myScript --node-args="value"`

I didnt expect this to work. What do I need to call to access my passed in arg correctly from the code instead of `argv.variable`? and can I still do something like

`--node-args="variable=value"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pm2 start file.js --name myScript --node-args="--variable=value -port 12345"
```

Alternatively, add `--`, followed by your script args:

```
pm2 start file.js --name myScript -- --variable=value -port 12345
```

Details: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/pm2-how-to-start-your-app-with-node-js-v8-arguments

Comment: why do you designate a port?

Comment: This was just an example how to pass multiple arguments...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it like this

`pm2 start script.js --name myScript -- -v=value`

and access it in code with

`var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));`

`console.log(argv.v);`

it only seemed to allow 1 letter variables.